Prestashop 8 CRON JOB custom modules on install
​
Hi
I have a custom module written for booking items to buy later. As a rule, it works practically correctly, except for removing items from the list of a given user.
However, the main problem is a CRON_JOB to check the database if the reservation time has already expired.
/reservationmodule/reservation_cron.php
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../init.php');

$reservations = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECTx * FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_reservations WHERE expiry_date < NOW()');

error_log('Processing of overdue bookings has begun.', 3, '/file.log');

foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
    $product = new Product($reservation['id_product']);
    $product->quantity++;
    if ($product->save()) {
        error_log('Updated quantity for product ID: ' . $reservation['id_product'], 3, '/file.log');
    } else {
        error_log('Error when updating quantities for product ID: ' . $reservation['id_product'], 3, '/file.log');
    }

    $deleted = Db::getInstance()->delete('product_reservations', 'id_reservation = ' . (int)$reservation['id_reservation']);
    if ($deleted) {
        error_log('Rezerwacja ID: ' . $reservation['id_reservation'] . ' has been removed.', 3, '/file.log');
    } else {
        error_log('Error when deleting ID reservations: ' . $reservation['id_reservation'], 3, '/file.log');
    }
}

error_log('Processing of overdue bookings has been completed.', 3, '/file.log');
?>

Main module class:
/reservation/reservation.php
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Reservation extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'reservation';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Your Name';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Product Reservation');
        $this->description = $this->l('Allows customers to reserve products for a specific number of days.');

        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7.0.0', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('actionFrontControllerSetMedia') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayCustomerAccount') &&
            $this->registerHook('displayAdminOrder') &&
            $this->createReservationTable() &&
            $this->installTab('AdminParentOrders', 'AdminReservations', 'Reservations') &&
            Configuration::updateValue('RESERVATION_DAYS', 7) &&
            $this->registerHook('actionCronJob') &&
            $this->registerCronTask();
    }

    public function hookActionCronJob($params)
    {
        if ($params['task'] === 'processExpiredReservations') {
            $this->processExpiredReservations();
        }
    }

    private function createReservationTable()
    {
        $sql = '
            CREATEx TABLEx IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_reservations` (
                x`id_reservation` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                x`id_product` INT(11) NOT NULL,
                x`date_reserved` DATETIME NOT NULL,
                x`expiry_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
                x`id_customer` INT(11) NOT NULL,
                x`customer_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (`id_reservation`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
        ';

        return Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall() &&
            $this->uninstallTab('AdminReservations') &&
            $this->deleteReservationTable() &&
            Configuration::deleteByName('RESERVATION_DAYS');
    }

    public function registerCronTask()
    {
        if (Module::isInstalled('cronjobs')) {
            return Db::getInstance()->insert('cronjobs', [
                'id_module' => $this->id,
                'task' => 'processExpiredReservations',
                'description' => $this->l('Przetwarzanie przeterminowanych rezerwacji'),
                'hour' => -1,
                'day' => -1,
                'month' => -1,
                'day_of_week' => -1,
                'active' => 1,
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ]);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function processExpiredReservations()
    {
        $reservations = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECTx * FROMx ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_reservations WHEREx expiry_date < NOW()');

        error_log('Rozpoczęto przetwarzanie przeterminowanych rezerwacji.', 3, _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/expired_reservations.log');

        foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
            $updateQuantityResult = StockAvailable::updateQuantity(
                $reservation['id_product'],
                $reservation['id_product_attribute'],
                $reservation['quantity'],
                $reservation['id_shop']
            );

            if ($updateQuantityResult) {
                error_log('Zaktualizowano ilość dla produktu ID: ' . $reservation['id_product'], 3, _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/expired_reservations.log');
            } else {
                error_log('Błąd przy aktualizacji ilości dla produktu ID: ' . $reservation['id_product'], 3, _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/expired_reservations.log');
            }

            $deleted = Db::getInstance()->delete('product_reservations', 'id_reservation = ' . (int)$reservation['id_reservation']);
            if ($deleted) {
                error_log('Rezerwacja ID: ' . $reservation['id_reservation'] . ' została usunięta.', 3, _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/expired_reservations.log');
            } else {
                error_log('Błąd przy usuwaniu rezerwacji ID: ' . $reservation['id_reservation'] . ' z bazy danych.', 3, _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/expired_reservations.log');
            }
        }

        error_log('Zakończono przetwarzanie przeterminowanych rezerwacji.', 3, _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/expired_reservations.log');
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        $output = '';
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitReservationSettings')) {
            $days = (int)Tools::getValue('RESERVATION_DAYS');
            if ($days <= 0) {
                $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Number of reservation days must be greater than 0.'));
            } else {
                Configuration::updateValue('RESERVATION_DAYS', $days);
                $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated.'));
            }
        }

        return $output . $this->renderForm();
    }

    public function renderForm()
    {
        $fields_form = array(
            'form' => array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Reservation Settings'),
                    'icon' => 'icon-cogs'
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Number of reservation days'),
                        'name' => 'RESERVATION_DAYS',
                        'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Set the number of days the reservation will be held.'),
                        'suffix' => $this->l('days'),
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
                )
            ),
        );

        $helper = new HelperForm();
        $helper->submit_action = 'submitReservationSettings';
        $helper->fields_value['RESERVATION_DAYS'] = Configuration::get('RESERVATION_DAYS');

        return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
    }

    private function deleteReservationTable()
    {
        $sql = 'DROPx TABLEx IFx EXISTSx `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_reservations`';
        return Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
    }

    private function installTab($parent, $className, $name)
    {
        $tab = new Tab();
        $tab->id_parent = (int) Tab::getIdFromClassName($parent);
        $tab->class_name = $className;
        $tab->module = $this->name;
        $tab->active = 1;

        foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
            $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = $name;
        }

        return $tab->add();
    }

    private function uninstallTab($class_name)
    {
        $id_tab = (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName($class_name);
        if ($id_tab) {
            $tab = new Tab($id_tab);
            return $tab->delete();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hookActionFrontControllerSetMedia($params)
    {
        if ('product' === $this->context->controller->php_self) {
            $this->context->controller->registerJavascript(
                'module-reservation',
                'modules/' . $this->name . '/views/js/reservation.js',
                ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 150]
            );
        }
    }

    public function hookDisplayCustomerAccount($params)
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'reservation_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('reservation', 'myReservations'),
        ]);
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/customer_account.tpl');
    }
}
?>




The problem is that these cronJobs are not executing. I wanted the cron_job.php file to execute every hour, or at least this defined task in the mim module.
I know that you can set up a crontab, but I won't have access to the server where the whole thing will be set up. So I wanted to achieve this with a module

Is it possible to set up such a cron_job so that it executes along with the module installation?
The SQL in the controllers was specifically broken so that this post could be published
​
ENV: Docker - official prestashop docker-compose
OS: Windows 10

Well windows does not have a CRON capability.  However it does have scheduled tasks!
